# Angular 2 Store a reactive form in LocalStorage

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a Reactive Form with angular 2 so that if the user were to refresh the page, or even come back days later, the form they were working on would still be filled out as they filled it out earlier. I'd like to store this form in local storage.

I tried doing something like ,

```
localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(this.myFormArray))
```

Where `this.myFormArray` is an array of forms.

However, when I do this, I get an error saying ...

```
RROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Alex

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach I would recommend is to have a unique id for each form, and then subscribe to the `form.valueChanges`, possibly with a debounce to not write on every keystroke, and then write to localStorage in the subscribe block. Or delegate to a service to do so (that way, you can change the persistence mechanism later if desired).

Then on init of your form, use something like `form.setValue(valObj)` with the retrieved value from the service for that id.

Answer (score 0):

structures that include circular references can't be serialized with JSON.stringify.use json-stringify-safe instead

https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe

it doesn't throw on circular references.

Comment: I don't believe this is the core problem. The problem is trying to store the whole form object, not just the value, which likely isn't circular.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this.myFormArray` , Use `this.myFormArray.value`
That will return a Normal Object that we can stringify.

So the entire flow on most use cases will be

```
myForm: FormGroup

ngOnInit() {
    const myForm = window.localStorage.getItem('myForm')

    // if form available set the values that are already filled

    if ( myForm ) {
        const values = JSON.parse(myForm)
        this.myForm.setValue(values)
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('myForm',JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value))
}
```